# $Ax=0$, $x \neq 0$ implies $A$ is singular

Tags: matrices

Where $A$ and $x$ are matrices. A proof of something relies upon this statement, but it's brushed over so quickly that it must be nearly trivial, I can't see it though!

Comment: What would happen if $A$ was invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is non-singular, let $A'$ be the inverse.  Then we have

$A'Ax = (A'A)x = Ix = x$ and

$A'Ax = A'(Ax) = A'0 = 0$

This contradicts the premise that $x$ is not $0$.

Comment: Thank you, how about the converse? If $A$ is singular there exists an $x \neq 0$ with $Ax=0$?

Comment: Just find 2 perpendicular vectors y and x.  Repeat y to make a square matrix of it.

Comment: @cb7 This points to the reality behind this problem.  A non-singular matrix $A$ forms an $n$-dimensional basis for an $n$-space, and it is impossible for $n$ basis vectors to all simultaneously be perpendicular to yet another vector $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We prove the contrapositive.

Let $A$ be a non-singular matrix; so $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$.

Suppose that $Ax = 0$.

Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ on the left to get $$A^{-1} A x = A^{-1} 0,$$ which gives $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming x is a vector and A is a square matrix. A being singular is the same as being non-invertible in this case. If A were invertible, there would be a matrix $A^{-1}$ called A 's inverse that knows how to send $Ax$ back to x, for all x. Namely,   $A^{-1}Ax = x$. To do this, each $ y = Ax$ needs to have a single x value that it results from. So if $Ax = Ax'$ then x = x'. We know that $A0 = 0$, so if A was invertible then $Ax = 0$ would have had to imply that x =0.